# Strange network quirk for ethernet-connected Brother DCP Printer, Buffalo Router (DD-WRT)

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet, network-printer, buffalo-router, brother-printer

I have Brother DCP-7065DN all-in-one hooked up to my Buffalo WHR-G300N router, which is running a recent (though not quite latest) build of DD-WRT, using an ethernet connection. For computers accessing the wireless network, the printer is visible as a normal network printer and will happily print on request.

However, if I attach a computer to the router via ethernet cable rather than via wireless connection, the printer is no longer visible to that computer on the network. As a result, I can perform network printing if and only if I'm on the wireless network – not when I'm on the wired network. This is at most inconvenient, but it is extremely perplexing.

I've tested and confirmed this behavior from two Macs – one running 10.8.2, one running 10.7's latest – and from a Windows PC running up-to-date Windows 7.

Brother tech support simply pointed me to their normal walkthrough documents, which were not helpful.

I can supply any data from the Buffalo router's settings, but don't know which pieces would be useful.

Comment: Are the wired and wireless devices on the same subnet? Check their IP addresses to find out. If they're not, I suspect the router is not set up to connect the subnets.

Comment: They are. Moreover, if you look at the configuration I outlined, they have to be: _wireless_ devices can print to the _wired_ printer. It's only _wired_ devices that can't.

Comment: Is this router also providing your Internet access? Which ports are the printer and wired computer connected to?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, it is—it's connected directly to my Motorola cable modem, and providing internet access to all the devices in the house (both wired and wireless). Are you meaning physical ports or TCP? They're both just connected to two normal outbound ethernet ports on the router (the inbound is hooked up to the Motorola cable modem).

Answer (score 0):

Exactly same situation here.
On the other hand, I believe this problem is due to the setting of Buffalo WHR-G300N router since my wired computer can print to the same printer while being connected via a 3-Com router instead of the Buffalo one. I also found that my computer can now access to the printer web page when I plug a ethernet cable between the computer and Buffalo router, but it loses the connection very soon.
Since I am now using the new Buffalo router, I can only do printing by transfering files to  wireless devices in advance. Of course, this way causes a great deal of inconvenience.

Comment: Yeah, I've guessed the problem was with the router and not the printer. The trick, of course, is that it's hard to figure out exactly what the issue is. Most likely, the "disappearing" connection you're seeing is a result of the delay between when you plug the computer in and when it shifts from using the wireless network to using the wired network (assuming you've left the wireless connection on), as most modern computers/OSes switch automatically to whichever provides a better connection. There's some delay while it gets IP from DHCP, etc.